# compiler cannot find @model MembershipUserCollection in a view - Asp Net MVC 4 Application

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

Why I am not able to use

```
@model MembershipUserCollection
```

nor

```
@model System.Web.Security.MembershipUserCollection
```

In my view.

Compiler complains saying that `MembershipUserCollection` is not found.

Comment: Do you have a reference to `System.Web.ApplicationServices` in your project?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. Check that you have a reference to System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll and check the target framework settings (are you using .NET 4?).

Comment: @Michael Perrenoud Yes, the reference is there. This happens only in the view. I am able to reference within the controller

Comment: @Davide Icardi. .Net 4.0.

Comment: does the compiler says any other error?

Comment: @lante No... just this. Type or namespace not found. Are you missing a using directive or a assembly reference? http://pbrd.co/WRnhoE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `using` statment

```
@using System.Web.Security
@model MembershipUserCollection

your html code
```

Comment: That wouldn't be the problem because `@model System.Web.Security.MembershipUserCollection` doesn't work either.

Comment: Yes.. you are right. See the problem here: http://pbrd.co/WRnhoE. At the moment I am having to use ViewBag to pass the collection but I want to avoid that